# "/bin/bash: bad interpreter: Text file busy" even though the file editor closed the file

Tags: linux, bash, samba

I have a script on Linux that I edit under Windows (through Samba), that starts with the shebang line `#!/bin/bash`.  Even though:

- I finish editing, save, and close the file in the editor
- make sure the file is not opened anywhere else
- make sure the file is saved with Unix line ending
- `cat` the file under Linux and make sure the edit is present
- `stat` the file under Linux and make sure it has the timestamp after editing

I still get the error `/bin/bash: bad interpreter: Text file busy` when I try to execute it, for a while (about a minute or two).  Why??

NOTE:  the file is *not* cached on the client.  The file is visible on the server by `cat`.  It is also possible to run `/bin/bash` on it.  It is *only* when the shebang line is used, that is, when the file *itself* is executed, that the above error happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samba supports something called opportunistic locking.

When a client wants to read a file and nobody is writing the file, Samba will give the client a read oplock. This allows the client to cache data without having to read it over and over from the server. If another client wants to write to the file, Samba will issue a "break oplock" request to the client with the oplock, so it knows it can't cache anymore.

Similarly, when a client wants to write a file and nobody else is accessing the file, Samba will give the client a write oplock. This allows it to buffer writes, cache reads and assume it can read its own writes back without having to bother the server. If another client wants to read from, or write to, the file, Samba will issue a "break oplock" request to the client with the oplock, forcing it to flush all its buffered writes and stop the buffering and caching.

What's happening is the Windows machine holds a write oplock. And since you're accessing the file from the host (rather than through Samba), Samba has no chance to ask the client to break the oplock. As a result, the server has no way to know whether the contents of the file are usable or whether the real contents are still known only to the client. Until the write oplock is broken, the file cannot be executed.

You can, if you wish, configure Samba not to use oplocks for that share, file, extension, or whatever makes sense. There will be a performance loss as caching and buffering will be reduced.

Comment: OK I researched Samba and I found that I don't need to disable locks altogether.  I can simply turn on `kernel oplocks = yes`.  What that should do, is, if a Unix process is trying to access the file that has a Samba oplock, the Samba server sends its locking client request to write back its copy, release the lock, and then allows the Unix process to proceed.  So I turned on this option - this improved the delay time, but not eliminated it completely.  Now I get the same error still, not for a minute, but for about 10 seconds, after writing the file on Windows.  Why?

Comment: thank you, following your answer I researched Samba locks and I still don't understand.  If the oplock were taken, it would mean, the file copy is locally cached on the Windows client.  That's not what is happening.  The file copy on Unix is _immediately_ updated after the edit, that is, a program such as `cat` displays it.  I can also execute it with `/bin/bash`.  It is only when the shebang line is used, that is, when the file itself is executed, that I run into the above problem.

Comment: "*If the oplock were taken, it would mean, the file copy is locally cached on the Windows client.*" That's just not true. The client doesn't have to do anything differently just because it has an oplock. It is free to completely ignore the fact that it has an oplock if it wants. The oplock just means the server must break the oplock before it can assume the file contents are updated because the client is permitted to buffer and cache.

Comment: thank you - I did RTFM, read the Samba docs, now I read your comments and I am confused, I am sorry.  I do want to ensure the client does caching, for improved performance. At the same time, I do want the server to send the client a request to write back the copy, when some other Unix process tries to access the servers copy.  How to do it?

Comment: what is confusing to me, is the problem _only_ happens when the shebang line is used.

Comment: @user461984 That's because without the shebang, the file is opened for reading rather than executing. A file can be opened for reading even if someone else can modify it, but to open it for executing, it must be locked exclusively.

Comment: what I also don't understand about your answer, is you seem to be saying, that Samba server does not know that another Unix process wants to access the file, so it cannot ask its client to break the lock.  According to Samba docs, that seems not to be true - specifically, by the use of `kernel oplocks = yes`, the server will notify the Linux kernel of locked files and the kernel will in return ask the server to break the lock.

Comment: OK I will ask another question to clarify.

Comment: @David Schwartz I have the same problem and I read your answer and discussion, and I don't understand one thing.  You say "Until the write oplock is broken, the file cannot be executed.".  That's not true...  For the OP, after a minute, the file _can_ be executed.  For me, it is about 12 seconds.  However, this depends on the Windows client.  Sometimes, depending on the client, the file can be executed immediately.  What does the client do differently in relations with Samba, so that Linux (not a Samba client) can execute the file at once, vs. with delay?

Comment: @David Schwartz and those editor clients that somehow manage interactions with Samba so the Linux file can be executed, and immediately after saving, do still have the file open after saving.  On the other hand, if an editor incurs a delay, even after the editor closes the file, the delay continues... But it's always the same Samba with the same settings...  So there must be some correct/incorrect way for the editor to deal with Samba regarding this situation?